# What is the word for people who have similar interests?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

I remember seeing a word somewhere that I didn't know, and when I searched it up it gave me a definition along the lines of "those who share similar interests" but I can't recall the word. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: _Kindred spirit_?

Comment: *cut from the same cloth*

Answer (score 0):

Many words fit your description, such as:

**Coterie:**

> A small group of people with shared interests or tastes, especially one that is exclusive of other people.
>
> > Oxford Dictionaries

They could also be called **"like-minded"**, although I doubt this is what you're looking for:

> having a like disposition or purpose : of the same mind or habit of thought
>
> > [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like-minded)

**Kindred Spirit:**

> a person whose interests or attitudes are similar to one's own
>
> > Oxford Dictionaries

A person could be called or a group could also be "*congenial*":

**Congenial**

> (of a person) pleasing or liked on account of having qualities or interests that are similar to one's own.
>
> > Oxford Dictionaries